# Identifying an invisible character in plain text file

Tags: regex, characters

I am working with a plain text file that has invisible characters that I do not recognise. How can I identify them?

In Atom, they show as blanks when I toggle to show invisible characters. They do not show as a common space (the one that Atom shows as a small centered dot).

In BBEdit, it shows as a centered dot that looks slightly thicker than the common space. Replacing non-ASCII characters (with 'zap gremlins') does not replace it.

I can copy the character into a regular expression, and the query will find the character. It is not recognised as a white space character with `\s`.

I will copy the character here (between the arrows), but I have no idea if it actually shows up! -> <-

(wow, pasting an unknown invisible character felt absurdly awkward...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a hex editor should reveal the hex codes you could then look up or search for.

If you wanted to stick with a (bash?) terminal, you could put the whole file through `hexdump` / `hd`, or maybe `grep` an offending line and just pipe it to `hd` so you're only looking at one line, similar to:

```
grep "unique line text" file | hd
```

Or get only the Nth line with
`sed 'Nq;d file'`

There's also the regular expression character class for all printable characters:

> ```
> ‘[:print:]’
>  Printable characters: ‘[:alnum:]’, ‘[:punct:]’, and space.
> ```

Searching for the inverse (`-v`) of those might be useful, like
`grep -v "[[:print:]]"`

Or if you can copy it successfully, you could just paste it into a hex editor, or an `echo " " | hd` command...

Comment: Thanks! Apparently it was a non-breaking space (`c2 a0`). In my regex `\u00A0` selects the character.